# How to get rid of extra slashes in pandas to_latex function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

I am trying to convert pandas data frame to latex format but it's returning extra slashes in the output.

Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model_name': {0: 'ALBERT', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}, 'macro_precision_first': {0: 91.89396817624747, 1: 92.17133890858452, 2: 92.6826295632407, 3: 92.80299948526579, 4: 93.34410168004217, 5: 92.0346638078341}, 'macro_recall_first': {0: 92.2318448502444, 1: 92.3357692328841, 2: 93.0292033013862, 3: 93.12015088280738, 4: 93.66748596470968, 5: 92.36958589707638}, 'macro_f1_first': {0: 91.95372391665576, 1: 92.23312713937592, 2: 92.71221623765801, 3: 92.88621653320901, 4: 93.43123707996612, 5: 92.1035266749227}})
```

When I am trying `df.to_latex()`, the output looks like this:

```
'\\begin{tabular}{llrrr}\n\\toprule\n{} & model\\_name &  macro\\_precision\\_first &  macro\\_recall\\_first &  macro\\_f1\\_first \\\\\n\\midrule\n0 &     ALBERT &                  91.89 &               92.23 &           91.95 \\\\\n1 &          a &                  92.17 &               92.34 &           92.23 \\\\\n2 &          b &                  92.68 &               93.03 &           92.71 \\\\\n3 &          c &                  92.80 &               93.12 &           92.89 \\\\\n4 &          d &                  93.34 &               93.67 &           93.43 \\\\\n5 &          e &                  92.03 &               92.37 &           92.10 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

What I am expecting is the rows like this:

```
ALBERT &                  91.89 &               92.23 &           91.95 \\ 
a      &                  92.17 &               92.34 &           92.23 \\
b      &                  92.68 &               93.03 &           92.71 \\
c      &                  92.80 &               93.12 &           92.89 \\
d      &                  93.34 &               93.67 &           93.43 \\
e      &                  92.03 &               92.37 &           92.10 \\
```

How I can get rid of extra slashes and `\\\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slashes are escape characters in the string. They are not really present. Try to print:

```
print(df.to_latex())
```

output:

```
\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
\toprule
{} & model\_name &  macro\_precision\_first &  macro\_recall\_first &  macro\_f1\_first \\
\midrule
0 &     ALBERT &              91.893968 &           92.231845 &       91.953724 \\
1 &          a &              92.171339 &           92.335769 &       92.233127 \\
2 &          b &              92.682630 &           93.029203 &       92.712216 \\
3 &          c &              92.802999 &           93.120151 &       92.886217 \\
4 &          d &              93.344102 &           93.667486 &       93.431237 \\
5 &          e &              92.034664 &           92.369586 &       92.103527 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```